# Add a link to existing menu - no access to change HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way i can add an additional link to an existing menu, where i don't have the ability to change the HTML of the menu , but i am granted access to add javascript/jquery to the site ?

Here is the current HTML of the menu

```
<div id="hsubmenu">
  <ul id="hsubmenuitems">
  <li><a href="http://www12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/home/31744">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/live_scoring_summary?L=31744">Live Scoring</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/standings?L=31744">Standings</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=101">Power Rank</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=15">Schedules</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=29">Message Board</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=79">Playoffs</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=08">Players Stats</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=156">League History</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=03">Transactions</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to add another menu item to the end

```
<li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=07">Rosters</a></li>
```

Comment: Yes there is, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can do this

```
var li = $('<li>') //Create new li item

li.append('<a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=07">Rosters</a>') //Add href

$("#hsubmenuitems").append(li); //Add this li item with href to "hsubmenuitems"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('<li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=07">Rosters</a></li>').appendTo('#hsubmenuitems');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jk63F/

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the innerHTML of the element to append your new item.

```
var listElement = document.getElementById('hsubmenuitems');

listElement.innerHTML += '<li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=07">Rosters</a></li>';
```

With jQuery the syntax is a little shorter.

```
$("#hsubmenuitems").append('<li><a href="http://football12.myfantasyleague.com/2014/options?L=31744&amp;O=07">Rosters</a></li>');
```